# statistic to measure degree of stationary

Tags: statistics

I want to claim the time series in figure 1 is more stationary than figure 2. However, [Augmented Dickey-Fuller test asserts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test asserts they are both stationary, at least at 90% confidence. But intuition, the distribution of figure 2 seems to be changing over time. Is there any statistic to measure the degree of stationary of a time series? Or any other way to support (or even refute) my claim? Thanks in advance.

[image: Time series 1]

[image: Time series 2]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that [time-frequency methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-frequency_analysis) are useful here. See if this helps:
[Measuring the degree of non-stationarity by using the Wigner-Ville spectrum](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1172740)